# Unable to connect mysql with my application inside kubernetes minikube

Tags: java, mysql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

When I started mysql-service and my application service (user-service), the user-service throws the error below. But the services work fine in docker container.

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> at >com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at >com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar!/:6.2.6.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar!/:6.2.6.Final]

Here are my configuration files
***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: "3"

services:

  mysqldb-docker:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysqldb
    networks:
      - app-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=flight_booking
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  user-service:
    image: user-service:1.0
    build:
      context: ./UserService
    container_name: user-service
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - app-mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb-docker
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB_HOST=mysqldb-docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service:3306/flight_booking?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldb-docker:

networks:
  app-mysql:
```

***mysqldb-deployment.yaml***

```
# mysqldb-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysqldb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysqldb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysqldb
          image: mysql:8.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysqldb
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: flight_booking
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysqldb-persistent-storage  # Reference the PVC name
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysqldb-persistent-storage  # Define the volume name
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysqldb-pvc  # Reference the PVC name you created earlier
```

***mysqldb-service.yaml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysqldb
  ports:
    - port: 3306
```

***mysqldb-pv.yaml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi  # Set the desired storage size
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  # Adjust based on your use case
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard  # Set the appropriate storage class
  hostPath:
    path: /path/to/host/mysqldb-data  # Adjust the host path to your desired location
```

***mysqldb-pvc.yaml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  # Must match the access mode in the PV
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi  # Must match the storage size in the PV
```

***user-service-deployment.yaml***

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-service-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1  # Set the desired number of replicas
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-service
          image: sweetyrv/flight_booking:user-service
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: flight_booking
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB_HOST
              value: mysqldb-service
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service:3306/flight_booking?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              value: root
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              value: root
```

***user-service-service.yaml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

I've tried checking network policies, hostname resolution, and even the MySQL server configuration. The fact that this configuration works in a Docker setup but not in Kubernetes is puzzling.

I would appreciate any insights on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. If you need any additional details, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Is the database actually starting up?  (Does `kubectl get pod` say it's in `Running` status?)  The manual PersistentVolume/Claim seem iffy to me; I might normally expect a database to use a StatefulSet, that will automatically create the PVC, and the cluster will automatically create the underlying PV.  The URL/Service/Pod wiring looks correct to me, assuming all of these parts are in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by the hostname you are trying to use to connect from service to db, here:

```yaml
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB_HOST
              value: mysqldb-service
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service:3306/flight_booking?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
```

it should be switched to kubernetes address, so instead of `mysqldb-service` probably `mysqldb-service.default.svc.cluster.local` (assuming you use `default` namespace and `cluster.local` as cluster domain, so:

```yaml
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB_HOST
              value: mysqldb-service.default.svc.cluster.local
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:3306/flight_booking?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
```

> the pattern for cluster address is `SERVICE_NAME.NAMESPACE.SVC.CLUSTER_DOMAIN`, so you might need to use diffrent values for `NAMESPACE` and/or `CLUSTER_DOMAIN`

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference: so long as the Pods and Services are in the same namespace, the `.namespace.svc.cluster.local` will be injected into the default DNS search path.